# Installation problems: pentaho 5.1 ce on JDK 1.8

Tags: exception, installation, pentaho

I'm very new to Pentaho, and I need to install it on my machine to start a BI project. I installed the last community version from the community website (biserver-ce-5.1.0.0-752), set the PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME to point to my JDK 1.8 installation and simply unzip the file and run

```
2014-07-22 00:02:48,669 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.util.logging.Logger] Error: Pentaho
2014-07-22 00:02:48,671 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.util.logging.Logger] misc-class org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.pluginmgr.DefaultPluginManager: PluginManager.ERROR_0011 - Failed to register plugin cgg
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from file [C:\Pentaho\biserver-ce\pentaho-solutions\system\cgg\plugin.spring.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Context namespace element 'annotation-config' and its parser class [org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigBeanDefinitionParser] are only available on JDK 1.5 and higher
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:420)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
    at org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.pluginmgr.DefaultPluginManager.getNativeBeanFactory(DefaultPluginManager.java:411)
    at org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.pluginmgr.DefaultPluginManager.initializeBeanFactory(DefaultPluginManager.java:439)
    at org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.pluginmgr.DefaultPluginManager.reload(DefaultPluginManager.java:189)
    at org.pentaho.platform.plugin.services.pluginmgr.PluginAdapter.startup(PluginAdapter.java:40)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem$2.call(PentahoSystem.java:398)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem$2.call(PentahoSystem.java:389)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.runAsSystem(PentahoSystem.java:368)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.notifySystemListenersOfStartup(PentahoSystem.java:389)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.access$000(PentahoSystem.java:77)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem$1.call(PentahoSystem.java:326)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem$1.call(PentahoSystem.java:323)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.runAsSystem(PentahoSystem.java:368)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.notifySystemListenersOfStartup(PentahoSystem.java:323)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.init(PentahoSystem.java:294)
    at org.pentaho.platform.engine.core.system.PentahoSystem.init(PentahoSystem.java:207)
    at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.context.SolutionContextListener.contextInitialized(SolutionContextListener.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4709)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:583)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:675)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:822)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Context namespace element 'annotation-config' and its parser class [org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigBeanDefinitionParser] are only available on JDK 1.5 and higher
    at org.springframework.context.config.ContextNamespaceHandler$1.parse(ContextNamespaceHandler.java:65)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:69)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1297)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:135)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:507)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:398)
    ... 42 more
```

I've done some research and found that I have to copy the content of the directory biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions/system/cgg/lib into tomcat/ into biserver-ce/tomcat/webapps/pentaho/WEB-INF/lib/. I did all of that, and after re-starting pentaho, I got the following error:

```
2014-07-21 23:34:13,281 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] Context initialization failedorg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Parser configuration exception parsing XML from file [C:\Pentaho\biserver-ce\pentaho-solutions\system\pentaho-spring-beans.xml]; nested exception is javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: Unable to validate using XSD: Your JAXP provider [org.apache.crimson.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl@6e171cd7] does not support XML Schema. Are you running on Java 1.4 with Apache Crimson? Upgrade to Apache Xerces (or Java 1.5) for full XSD support.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:412)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:92)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:123)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:422)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:352)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4709)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:583)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:675)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:822)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: Unable to validate using XSD: Your JAXP provider [org.apache.crimson.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl@6e171cd7] does not support XML Schema. Are you running on Java 1.4 with Apache Crimson? Upgrade to Apache Xerces (or Java 1.5) for full XSD support.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.createDocumentBuilderFactory(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:102)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:70)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No attributes are implemented
    at org.apache.crimson.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.setAttribute(DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.java:93)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.createDocumentBuilderFactory(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:99)
    ... 39 more
```

I finally tried to install and run the 5.0 stable version, without being more lucky... got this error now

```
2014-07-22 00:38:03,701 ERROR [org.springframework.extensions.jcr.JcrSessionFactory] Error registering nodetypes org.apache.jackrabbit.spi.commons.conversion.IllegalNameException: empty name
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.spi.commons.conversion.NameParser.parse(NameParser.java:58)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.spi.commons.conversion.ParsingNameResolver.getQName(ParsingNameResolver.java:64)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.spi.commons.conversion.CachingNameResolver.getQName(CachingNameResolver.java:76)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.spi.commons.conversion.DefaultNamePathResolver.getQName(DefaultNamePathResolver.java:74)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.SessionImpl.getQName(SessionImpl.java:638)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.session.SessionContext.getQName(SessionContext.java:326)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.spi.commons.nodetype.AbstractItemDefinitionTemplate.setName(AbstractItemDefinitionTemplate.java:93)
    at org.pentaho.platform.repository2.unified.jcr.sejcr.ntdproviders.LocaleNtdProvider.getLocaleNode(LocaleNtdProvider.java:45)
    at org.pentaho.platform.repository2.unified.jcr.sejcr.ntdproviders.LocaleNtdProvider.getNodeTypeDefinition(LocaleNtdProvider.java:37)
    at org.pentaho.platform.repository2.unified.jcr.sejcr.CredentialsStrategySessionFactory.registerNodeTypes(CredentialsStrategySessionFactory.java:178)
    at org.pentaho.platform.repository2.unified.jcr.sejcr.CredentialsStrategySessionFactory.afterPropertiesSet(CredentialsStrategySessionFactory.java:152)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1369)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:269)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1245)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:269)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:495)
    at 
...........
```

Please guys, help me... Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pentaho 5.1 was not tested and does not support JDK 1.8.

I'd advise running jdk 1.7.

Remember that you can set the path to java JRE in the enviroment variable PENTAHO_HOME. This way you do not need to change JAVA_HOME.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! BTW, do you know if there is a way to get the same kind of tools available for the EE through the community? Especially for reporting and dashboard. Thanks a lot

Comment: The Ctools also work with the EE version. All plugins that work in CE also work in EE.

Comment: Pedro is Right. To see the the explanation of the problem see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23813369/spring-java-error-namespace-element-annotation-config-on-jdk-1-5-and-high

Comment: For the Java version, the variable is called PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME, and it should be a JDK version, [as Apache Tomcat expects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20469317/setting-up-tomcat-7-on-server-nb-java-home-should-point-to-a-jdk-not-jre)

Answer (score 1):

You have to patch JdkVersion properly - get [JdkVersion.java for spring 2.5.6](http://grepcode.com/file_/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring/2.5.6/org/springframework/core/JdkVersion.java/?v=source)

add couple lines like

```
if (javaVersion.contains("1.9.")) {
    majorJavaVersion = JAVA_19;
}
else if (javaVersion.contains("1.8.")) {
    majorJavaVersion = JAVA_18;
}
```

compile it for java 1.4 (it is worth to use java 1.7 or less):

```
$ javac -source 1.4 -target 1.4 org/springframework/core/JdkVersion.java
```

check it has the proper bytecode class version

```
$ javap -v org/springframework/core/JdkVersion.class | grep "major version"
major version: 48
```

patch spring-2.5.6.jar and spring-core-2.5.6.jar like

```
$ jar uvf spring-2.5.6.jar org
```

check that no other spring-2.5.6.jar or spring-core-2.5.6.jar in classpath (it could be in plugins as well)