# Tomcat 7 fails to install as service when JAVA_HOME points to JRE

Tags: java, tomcat

We are trying to install tomcat as a service at a client. The client currently has JAVA_HOME pointing to JRE and is refusing to change it.

While trying to install using service.bat install, we see the error as
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE

Does TOMCAT need JAVA_HOME pointing to JDK only?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20469317/setting-up-tomcat-7-on-server-nb-java-home-should-point-to-a-jdk-not-jre

Comment: Or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16726897/what-tomcat-requires-jdk-or-jre

Comment: So just for TOMCAT, JAVA_HOME should point to a full JDK installation and not JRE ..is that correct?

Comment: Do you want JSP(s) to work?